# Different URIs for GeoTargeting of web pages - correct?

Tags: caching, geolocation, uri

I manage a software companies website, which has some content that is geotargeted for 4 different markets (US, UK, AU, NZ)

- On the homepage 2 country specific case studies are included
- On some other pages, a single link may change based on the market

Currently the url for these pages is the same, independent of the market targeted.

The CMS used for this site has a page level caching feature, which we currently cannot use. To enable page level caching, we would like to have the homepage redirect based on geo targeting location, ie. to website.com/us, website.com/uk, website.com/au etc, so that each page can be cached.

Apart of anecdotal evidence from major company websites ([Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/en-gb), [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/default.aspx), [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/ie/index.html)), are there any alternatives to enabling page level caching or for example proxy caching and what are approximate effort and cost of setup.

Is there any RFC or best practice documentation that shows this is the right path to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has some guidelines for multi-regional websites including info on:

- [Managing multilingual versions of your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1)
- [Targeting site content to a specific country](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2)
- [Duplicate content and international sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#3)